# Dependency injection in `ActionFiliter` vs. calling `Activator.CreateInstance()`

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Requiring to sometimes use dependency injection in `ActioFilter` or other attributes running before or after an action API or result is inevitable. However, it is carried out through passing the type to be injected to the attribute using the `typeof` keyword. In order to simplify the case, when having various implementations for an interface, I have found it much simpler to manually instantiate the type than using the built-in dependency injection framework. For example:

```
public TestAttribute: Attribute, IActionFilter {
   private Type injectionType;
   public TestAttribute(Type injectionType){
     ... 
   }
   ...
   public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
       InjectedTypeInterface injectedTypInterface = (InjectedTypeInterface) Activator.CreateInstance(injectedType, arg1, arg2, ...);
       ...
   }
}
```

I want to know, from the point of view of other people here, that would this approach cause problems that using the built-in dependency injection framework would not? (Injected implementation will be always Transient in this case and not Scoped or Singleton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend doing the route of `Activator.CreateInstance`, here are some reasons why to avoid it and stick with the official way:

1. You'd need to pass in all instances of the parameters (i.e. of the type you want to instantiate has other dependencies) to it
2. The instance created this way isn't tracked by the scoped container. This also means, it won't automatically get disposed (**Updated note** this of course will only happen if the service implements `IDisposable` interface) at the end of the request and instead be disposed at some indeterminable time in future, when the GC kicks in and will keep resources open for longer then intended (i.e. holding connection or file handle open for longer then intended) unless you dispose it explicitly
3. Like you already recognized, you can't do so with scoped and singleton instances

For your concrete examples, there are easier ways to get a specific instance from DI - aside from the official supported ways ([Filters - Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#dependency-injection)) - you can also resolve from `HttpContext`, assuming you have access to it in the type of filter you are using.

For `ActionFilter`/`IActionFilter`

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
    InjectedTypeInterface injectedTypInterface = context.HttpContext
        .RequestServices.GetService<InjectedTypeInterface>();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Well, the most amazing part about your answer is the number 2. Because I really didn't realize it. What do you think if I implement I disposable and use it in a `using` block. The 1st one is no issue to me, because I need to pass arguments to the constructor manually that cannot be done using DI.

Comment: Are any of the parameters dependencies from DI? If so, using a factory pattern may be better solution. Then you can inject the dependencies into the factory and have a method `public T Create(string param1, int param2)`. It's still not tracked (but it's dependencies are). Also if the parameters are Attribute properties, you can use `TypeFilter` from above. If they are dynamic, well factory pattern mentioned earlier

Comment: I tried using DI, but it seems like it is not possible with the built-in framework. Because, the injected type to the filter differs from one action to another and I cannot specify it like that.

Comment: Share your code. You should definitely be able to use DI and get the same injected service between filters within the scope of a request (assuming the services in question are added to DI using Scoped lifetime). Did you try the TypeFilter subtype shown in the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#dependency-injection